# Simulate pressing a key for x milliseconds

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently working on a project that requires to be able to simulate the pressure of a key during a certain period of time. I'm using the keybd_event function to simulate pressing and releasing the key.

But if I add a timer between pressing and releasing the key in this way (example with the 'v' key) :

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    //time to enter on the notepad
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    // press v
    keybd_event(VkKeyScan('v'), 0, 0, 0);

    //desired pressing time
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    // release v
    keybd_event(VkKeyScan('v'), 0, 2, 0);

}
```

This only works for the simulation of a single character, it doesn't take into account the fact that I'd like the key press to last 2 seconds (which will create multiple 'v' characters).

I also wanted to ask you if, to solve this problem, I should not try to do a keystroke for a while, by looping the keystroke simulation, but I don't know if keyboards work like that. This would be like doing a loop, asking the timer for a loop every time it passes to see if it is not finished.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  `keybd_event` sends a single keystroke, it doesn't simulate the repeat behavior of a key being held down.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes indeed it is in this that my problem arises. But I was wondering if the keyboard, once a key is held down for a while, doesn't simply loop as if the user presses the key repeatedly. If this is the case, then I could solve my problem by using ```keybd_event```, looping the previous code while the timer finishes.

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that, as the keyboard hardware and driver are also involved, but yeah I think you could just try looping and see if that works.  It may or may not.

Comment: I'm new here thanks for your help I'll edit the tags. I put the C++ tag just in case there was a function in C++ that would solve my problem. I don't really use ```keybd_event``` it's just because I might have found a solution with the loop using it. By the way, I'm going to test this right now.

Comment: I come back to tell you that unfortunately the loop solution doesn't work, ```keybd_event``` simulates the pressing and releasing of a key far too quickly so that in a few seconds it creates far too much character that a keyboard would normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keybd_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) has been deprecated, you should use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead. The simulation api cannot directly simulate the repeat of keystrokes. You may need to simulate repeated keystrokes by detecting the keyboard repeat-delay & repeat-speed setting with [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)(`SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY`&`SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED`) and simulating it with `SendInput` by the time you got.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void keypress(double ms)
{
    int cout = 0;
    INPUT input[2] = {};
    input[0].type = input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = input[1].ki.wVk = 0x56;//'v'
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = input[1].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));
    cout++;
    int vParamDelay = 0;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY, 0, &vParamDelay, 0);
    int delayms = (vParamDelay + 1) * 250;
    DWORD vParamSpeed = 0;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED, 0, &vParamSpeed, 0);
    double ms_0 = (double)1000 / 2.5;
    double ms_31 = (double)1000 / 30;
    double slope = (ms_0 - ms_31) / 31;
    double speedms = ms_0 - slope * vParamSpeed;

    ms -= delayms;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    input[1].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    while (ms > speedms)
    {
        SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
        ms -= speedms;
    }
    SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main() {
    Sleep(3000);
    keypress(5500);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand much, but if all you want to do is press the "v" key for a while, I think you can do it like this :

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::chrono::seconds duration(2); // For how long do you want to toggle v in seconds
    long interval = 50; // How much time will be spend between each v

    auto end = duration + std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    while (std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end) {

        // press v
        keybd_event(VkKeyScan('v'), 0, 0, 0);

        //desired pressing time
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));

        // release v
        keybd_event(VkKeyScan('v'), 0, 2, 0);
    }

}
```

### What I did

While I didn't finish looping for n seconds (Duration), I press V each n ms (Interval)

Comment: I suggest that you make the `long duration` a proper `std::chrono::seconds` so that the comment _or_ casting isn't even needed. Better stay in the `chrono` land for as long as possible.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Set `end` before the loop, and never touch it again:
`auto end = start + std::chrono::seconds(2);

while (std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end) { ... }` - Also, for these kinds of loops you probably want `steady_clock`, not `system_clock`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's pretty much what I did for my test but not knowing the interval at which the keyboard executes the character, I didn't put any. But my problem was to be able to keep a key pressed for a while. The fact that the keyboard repeatedly executes a character is only a hypothesis on my part. I'm afraid that one key press will actually correspond to only one input for the system and then we'll make multiple ones. My goal is to reproduce the exact interpretation that the system produces when a key is pressed during some time. Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please consider closing it, so that user, can spend time resolving unresolved issues. 

Comment: As I told you, this is an alternative solution but I would still like to see if one has a "clean" version resulting in only one input. If I don't have any other solution after waiting a bit, I would close this question :)